# Apache CSV parser: Issue with ignoring empty lines

Tags: java, apache, csv

How to Ignore empty lines? I am using the below snippet of code and it doesnt ignore the empty lines.  Any pointer configuration available in CSV parser to fix this issue?

```
 public CSVParser parseCSV(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            return new CSVParser(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                    .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                    .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                    .withSkipHeaderRecord()
                    .withIgnoreEmptyLines()
                    .withTrim());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IPRSException(e);
        }
    }
```

Sample file

```
h1,h2,h3
d1,d2,d3
,,,
```

Expected output

```
d1,d2,d3
```

Comment: Is `,,,` an empty line or a non-empty line with no values?

Comment: its a empty line. I convert xlsx file to csv and when there is an empty line in xlsx, in CSV its ended up as ,,,

Comment: .withIgnoreEmptyLines doesnt seems to be working

Comment: So what's your actual output (as opposed to your expected output)?

Comment: actual output is : d1,d2,d3

Comment: So your actual output matches your expected output? What's the problem then?

Comment: Poor title. Edit to describe your specific technical issue. Also, if you are using the *Apache Commons CSV* library, say so explicitly, and maybe link to the project for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache CSV parser doesnt support empty lines out of the box, so ended up writing custom code.

```
private boolean isEmpty(CSVRecord csvRecord){
        if (null == csvRecord) return true;
        for (int i = 0; i < csvRecord.size(); i++) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(csvRecord.get(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public List<Map<String, Object>> getMapFromCSV(InputStream inputStream) {
        try {
            CSVParser parser = parseCSV(inputStream);
            return getMap(parser.getRecords().stream()
                    .sequential().filter(v -> !isEmpty(v))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()), parser.getHeaderMap());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }

  private List<Map<String, Object>> getMap (List<CSVRecord> records, Map<String, Integer> headers) {
        Map<Integer, String> headerMap = formatHeaderMap(headers);
        List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < records.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                CSVRecord record = records.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < record.size(); j++) {
                    map.put(headerMap.get(j), record.get(j));
                }
                data.add(map);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }


 private Map<Integer, String> formatHeaderMap(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        Map<Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        map.forEach((k , v) -> data.put(v, inputSanitizerForUtf8(k)));
        return data;
    }
```